# Creating a per module git repo environment for magento module development on one site

Tags: git, magento, gitignore

I want to develop multiple Magento modules on one fresh install of Magento 1.7 so that each module can be pushed to an online repo and tracked individually.

I initially began by following [this tutorial](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-setup-git-for-magento-extension-development/) but can't get Magento to detect the module using symlinks. I have enabled the 'follow symlinks' option in the backend. I could be struggling here due to file permissions or something but I don't mind abandoning this approach for a .gitignore "whitelist". Something like

```
 *
 !app/etc/modules/My_Module.xml
 !app/etc/code/community/My/Module
 !app/etc/code/community/My/Module/*
```

This seems a much easier approach but where do I initialise each working directory because they are all spread out from `./` I need to `git init` many repositories at the same locations each with different `.gitignore` files. I'd actually prefer the symlinking options because it gives me one place i can package my extensions from. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That tutorial references it, but if you haven't tried it yet I would recommend using [modman](https://github.com/colinmollenhour/modman) as a much less maintenance heavy option compared to creating all the symlinks manually as per the tutorial.  It will do an identical job, and will automatically create the symlinks for you according to a simple configuration file allowing you to develop externally to the magento install and thus create a repository containing only the extension which it sounds like you would prefer.

It's worth checking permissions and ownership of the files in your install - note that symlinks themselves will only themselves ever have permissions of 777 (world read/write) but will use the permissions of the file they reference, so check the permissions of the files you are symlinking to which will need to be sufficient for the web server user to access them.

With respect to using a whitelist, you can't initialise multiple repositories at the same location, but branching would be another solution if you don't mind all extensions being in the same repository just on different branches.

To my mind considering your requirements using modman with correct user and group ownership and permissions is going to offer you the best solution.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Sadly I think my boss is going to say it will take too long and I'll just have to keep writing modules on a per-site basis. :/

Comment: It will take a bit of time to get up and running but you could always try and convince your boss by giving him the argument that it can also be used to easily deploy extensions to multiple magento installs, the wiki has information on that.

Comment: I have set up the development environment using modman. This tool is terrific and I would say essential for anyone doing a reasonable amount of development work on Magento or another system that has the same folder structure 'issue'. I have written a guide to setting up a development environment for Magento modules using modman. PM me if you would like a link.

Comment: Great solution, I found a great tutorial in order to master this tool https://www.maxpronko.com/blog/magento-2-module-in-a-separate-repository